# Is there an ant wrapper for scala similar to antwrap in ruby?

Tags: scala, ant, wrapper

Do scala has a wrapper similar to http://antwrap.rubyforge.org/. I understand it would be quick easy to call ant methods directly from the REPL of as a script but was wondering if there is a DSL or wrapper around ant?

Comment: you can also use Ant build directly just add a dependency on scala-library.jar

Answer (score 3):

I think [SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) is what yo are looking for essentially. It uses Scala 2.7 syntax but most of the time you barely need to write any script at all as long as you stick to a directory structure. It uses Ant and Ivy underneath and has excellent integration with Ant+Ivy and Maven based projects. You should definitely check it out. It's super easy to get started.

**Update**:

So I didn't read closely enough of the question it seems. I believe [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/0.9.2/docs/userguide/ant.html) can do what you want. Gradle also has a [Scala plugin](http://www.gradle.org/scala_plugin.html). The downside is that this requires learning yet another language just to be able to write a build script. In the end you'll be using Groovy to write a Gradle build script that invokes an Ant build.xml that calls into Java to build a Scala project for you. This sounds like a lot of work.

BTW, you always have the choice to use JRuby and antwrap together. I don't want to know how slow this will be though.

Comment: I know about SBT, I am actually trying to run ant task defined in a jar within SBT. Taking advantages of ant project would be quite useful within SBT.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Take a look and see if this is really what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have checked: No, there isn't.

Most people seem to use [SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/), which has a slightly different feature set, but does an excellent job at building/running/deploying/testing/packaging.